# Drupal 7: add Taxonomy: all terms

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-6, migration, drupal-taxonomy

I am upgrading my website from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7.
In my view, Taxonomy: All terms field is present in drupal 6. In drupal 7 , I want to add this field but the problem is this filed is not present what should i do for?

Answer (score 1):

For D7 (Views 3.x) this may have changed into "`Content: All taxonomy terms`".